# Unable to promote member server to domain controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

We have a domain called test-companyname.com containing three DCs, namely XXX01, XXX02, and XXX03. All three machines are running 2008 R2. We had to add a new DC into the domain, which would be a 2012 R2 machine.

In the process, I have a user who is part of Domain / Enterprise / Schema Admins, with whom I am trying to promote my 2012 R2 member server to a DC.

In the last phase I get an error -

> Adprep execution failed - System.ComponentModel.System32Exception (0x80004005)

In Debug Logs:

> Adprep Log - If the error is "Insufficient Rights" (Ldap error code 50), please make sure the specified user has rights to read/write objects in the schema and configuration containers, or log off and log in as an user with these rights and rerun forestprep. In most cases, being a member of both Schema Admins and Enterprise Admins is sufficient to run forestprep.
>
> Entry DN: CN=Top,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=XXX,DC=local
> Add error on entry starting on line 617: Insufficient Rights

The server side error is: 0x2098 Insufficient access rights to perform the operation.

The extended server error is:

> 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03150BB9, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0

An error has occurred in the program

Working on this for past 12 hours with many teams and am unable to find the root cause. Really strange, this one!

Comment: Are all the DC's that have been recorded as FSMO role holders online and functioning? Use `netdom query fsmo` to query the FSMO holders.

Comment: Yeah , they are up and running perfectly fine .

Comment: Try to manually run `adprep /forestprep` while logged on to the Schema holder, and `adprep /domainprep` while logged on to the Infrastructure master.

Comment: This might sound pointless, but are you sure that your account is still in the Schema Admins and Domain Admins groups? Some domains might have those groups controlled by a GPO. GPO-restricted groups will automatically remove any members that get added manually.

Comment: What tool are you using to perform the Promotion? Server Manager GUI or PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to launch your Command Prompt or PowerShell window as an elevated process.

Right-click on the Command Prompt (or PowerShell) shortcut and select "Run as Administrator". *This is required even if you are already logged on as an administrator*.

Also, make sure that the user account is still in the Domain Admins and Schema Admins groups. It is possible that a group policy setting could be removing the account from restricted groups such as these two.

Now, try `dcpromo` again or `adprep /forestprep /domainprep`. It should work fine.